# Why does my GridView give me an `allowDefinition='MachineToApplication'` error?

Tags: .net, asp.net

What does this error mean in the context of a GridView?

> It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unlikely that this error has anything to do with your Gridview control.  It is more likely that, as the message suggests, you have not configured the virtual directory for your website as an application in IIS.  Right-click the website in IIS and check its properties.

Answer (score 2):

go to IIS and convert the virtual directory to an application using the button "create application"

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed the first scenario to check. However, the most frustrating scenario in which this error occurs is after a build/publish under a different build configuration (i.e. build under Release, and then trying to build under Debug and getting this error). You should perform Clean operation on the Release mode.

See this answer which points to further details: [Error: allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355947/error-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyond-application-level/2897171#2897171)