# Error: allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have downloaded the online project in ASP.Net.  While running application I get an error

> It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

What changes should i make in web.config or elsewhere to make this work?

Comment: None of the answers found on the web worked for me. My issue was solved by showing all hidden files/folders and deleting the `obj` folder.

Comment: This problem still manifests in VS2012.  I have opened a bug report with Microsoft.  Anyone experiencing the issue please upvote the bug report https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779737/error-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyond-application-level

Comment: deleting the obj folder resolved this issue for me as well. thanks @Nick! (sorry for the revival)

Comment: SOLUTION HERE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300927/error-to-use-a-section-registered-as-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyo/9301369#9301369

Comment: in my case, the extra web.config in a sub folder cause this problem. When I remove that extra web.config the error is gone

Answer (score 97):

I've just encountered this "delight".  It seems to present itself just after I've published a web application in release mode.

The only way to consistently get round the issue that I've found is to follow this checklist:

1. Clean solution whilst your solution is configured in Release mode.
2. Clean solution whilst your solution is configured in Debug mode.
3. Build whilst your solution is configured in Debug mode.

Comment: Only answer that worked for me also. I had many other errors waiting for me after this but they were unrelated. I got here by setting `MvcBuildViews` to `true`.

Comment: +1 BTW: I think the reason this worked for me was that the most recent build I had was **Debug**. I opened the solution, did a bug fix and attempted to build in R**Release** mode. Cleaning in **Release** didn't work but cleaning in **Debug** did. (Probably a combo of the 2 was what was needed, i.e. clear out **any** old refs to dlls, whether **Debug** or **Release**).

Comment: I did a **clean**, then went to ***project properties -> Web -> Create Virtual Directory** and then the issue was resolved

Comment: A clean and rebuild while in debug mode are all that is needed for me.  No need to switch back and forth between release and debug.  But yes, the CLEAN is very important.  That's the heart of the matter.

Comment: Why is this not marked as the correct solution? Saved my arse today with a cranky VS2015 project that suddenly decided to go badly sideways. At least it has the highest votes…

Comment: Maybe this will help those not running a .Net application. I am using Visual Studio for my HTML/JavaScript web application and I do not have access to IIS on my work laptop. So, going to Website -> Start Options -> Build and selecting "No Build" before running start page will keep the error from happening. Since it is not a .Net application, I do not need it to build before running.

Comment: After deploying the web-app on Internet and when I want to go to the admin page (/umbraco), I got same error. Please visit my question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/40923344/1817640

Comment: I have an external site where I created a subfolder and put my Web API files/folders which also has a Web.config file. Any idea?

Comment: Clean is not available in my case, which i have never seen before. This is a very old VB.NET application I inherited from a former colleague.

Answer (score 82):

Just come across [this post](http://sellsbrothers.com/12673) and that was happening to me.
Just `Clean` the project and the error goes away. (must be a VS2010 bug)

Comment: this solution if you get this as an Error in Visual Studio.

Comment: Sometimes clean doesn't clear out the `obj` folder. This sometimes needs deleting too.

Comment: Neither Clean nor deleting obj worked. Johnny Reilly's solution worked for me.

Comment: I had to run clean in both debug and release modes to get rid of this. Running it for just debug did not seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Same problem still exists in VS2013SP1.  A simple clean lets me deploy again.

Comment: VS2012 - "Clean" still does not work in my experience.  The only way to be sure of a clean is to delete the build folders yourself.

Comment: "Clean" didn't delete items in the obj folder. Open folder in file explorer > delete obj folder worked for me.

Comment: The post listed above is no longer available.

Comment: @jcaruso Corrected the URL, but the post only says that you need to run Clean on the project

Answer (score 25):

I have just had this problem when building a second version of my website. It didn't happen when I built it the first time.

I have just deleted the bin and obj folders, run a Clean Solution and built it again, this time without any problem.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me in VS Express 2012 for Web. Also, I only started getting this error after I created a solution configuration, and added MvcBuildViews set to true to its PropertyGroup in the .csproj source.

Answer (score 20):

None.  You need to set up the directory you've placed the website as a [web application within IIS](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/b5488995-fa99-460f-96d7-29d1ddcf3fac.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: Although technically that's a change "elsewhere to make this work" ;)

Comment: and this is the solution if you get this as an error in your web app! =P

Comment: I was already setup as an application. Johnny Reilly's solution worked in my case.

Comment: I am just trying to get the template Webforms app to work. It is fine on localhost but not on a server on the LAN. This solution worked for me: VS2015 CE, Windows Server 2008 on my LAN. I used this MS page to explain what to do on IIS: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/917413 . No changes to the template code.

Answer (score 16):

This error occurs when you attempt to open a project as a website.  The easiest way to determine if you've created a website or a project is to check your solution folder (i.e. where you saved your code) and see if you have a *.sln file in the root directory, if you do then you've created a project.

Just to add, I encountered this error just now when I attempted to open a project I created a while back by selecting "File", "Open Website" from the Visual Studio menus whereas I should have selected "File", "Open Project" instead. I facepalmed as soon as I realised :)

Comment: this was my problem too

Answer (score 13):

If you have MVC project with enabled views build, one of the solution is to delete obj folder before build. Add to project file:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <!-- Remove obj folder -->
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)" />
    <!-- Remove bin folder -->
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(BaseOutputPath)" />
</Target>
```

Here is article: [How to remove bin and/or obj folder before the build or deploy](http://kitsula.com/Article/How-to-remove-bin-obj-folder-before-build-deploy)

Answer (score 13):

In Visual Studio 2013 I struggled with this for a while and it is pretty much easy to solve *just follow what the exceptions says* **"virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS"**

In my case I had `WebService` planted inside `IIS website` so

1. I opened the website in IIS manager
2. right clicked the WCF folder
3. clicked `Convert to Application`
4. and then submitted with `Ok`

WCF is back and running.

Comment: I was encountering this issue when I moved my application to Default Website. Point 3 did the trick to resolve my problem.

Comment: This worked for me when we moved to a new web server. After doing a "Convert to Application", the folder symbol changed, and the ASP.NET MVC webapp started working on that web server.

Answer (score 11):

The error suggests that the code you are using is expecting a virtual directory to be setup on IIS.

Look up the documentation and add the required virtual directory. It should be a directory that has a `web.config` in it (not the root directory).

Comment: Removing a second web.config in a lower directory solved the issue for me.

Comment: One of my guys had his `<authentication mode="Forms"><forms name="..." loginUrl="~/Login/Login/" timeout="2880" /></authentication>` in his `Web.config` in the `Views` rather then the trunk folder, which caused this problem.

Answer (score 8):

A recent web.config change may be in the wrong web.config file.

A `<machineKey...>` property had been added to **Views/web.config**. No matter how many Cleans and Rebuilds the error remained. The fix was to move the property into the root **/web.config**.

Comment: We had accidentally copied the parent Web.config into the /Views folder.  Put the original, much smaller version for the Views folder in there and the site worked again.

Answer (score 6):

if you ever encounter this error

> It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS

**SOLUTION**
I had the same issue with VS 2012. 
I resolved this by

1. Unload your current project
2. edit your .csproj
3. Find this `<MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>`
4. Instead of **false** change the value to **true**
5. Load again your project and you should not have any more this error

If you do have then one solution is to delete the content of the obj folder in the project generated by compiler.

Comment: That's weird, setting `MvcBuildViews` to `true` is how I got the error in the first place.

Comment: I also started getting the error message after changing MvcBuildViews to true. I got rid of the error message by changing the value back to false.

Comment: I did a "Clean solution" in *both* release and debug modes and now the build is working also with `<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>`

Comment: I had exactly the opposite situation to the @visar_uruqi one. I mean in my **.csproj** file I had the option MvcBuildViews set to true and when I set to false the error was omitted (not shown).

Comment: I tell you VS 2013 is a heaven you should upgrade immediately, you won't get any of this annoying errors

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the problem appeared only *after I published the project* to the subdirectory. Because of my lack of knowledge, I have placed my `web_publish` subdirectory inside the `web_project` directory.

It is clear that the `web_publish` contains also the same `Web.config`s that the project contains. However, the `web_project` does not know that my `web_publish` should be avoided when searching `Web.config`s in the nested subdirectories. This way, the `Web.config`s were duplicated and the error appeared.

The solution was to place my `web_publish` somewhere else.

Comment: Well this indeed is the problem of multiple Web.config in your project.
Just check your project file and see if the "web.config" is not marked as always copy to output directory. <Content Include="Web.config">
      <!-- <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory> -->
    </Content>

Answer (score 5):

In my case there was a "Backup" folder which contained another copy of the whole website in there. This meant another `web.config` and so the build failed with this error. I deleted the "Backup" folder, did a Clean solution on the Debug and Release builds, and the error disappeared.

Comment: I had a similar situation, someone had created a "Published" subfolder within the Website root on the disk (this is an old Web Project, one of the ones with no Solution file), and this had a Web.config in it. 
The error occurred when Visual Studio tried to build it, and no amount of Cleaning/Deleting "obj" folders etc fixed that, of course.
I've seen quite a few instances of this error, and it's almost always a duplicate Web.config hiding away somewhere... (really poor error message as well!)

Answer (score 4):

In my case,

Solution contains 6 projects, 1 main and 5 sub directories. all the sub directories having web.config.

When running any page within sub directories, I was getting same error.

I removed this line from web.config,

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

that worked for me.

Comment: The line was there but not showing due to some indent problem I guess. I edited and pasted the code in a code block, it shows now. Please check and let me know if I could help in something.

Comment: Thanks, that confirms the line that it was failing on for me too. I only have one site, so I got around it by opening as a Web Site rather than a project.

Answer (score 4):

Clean your project
Remove the /obj folder (probably using publish and deploy? - there is a bug in it)

Comment: Only solution that worked for me. Got here by setting <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was I had accidentally published my webservice to a pre-completed location on a fresh install of VS2010.

I had published to a folder called **PreCompiledWeb**, and the presence of the web.config I suspect messed it up.

I simply nuked the folder, and refreshed the project.

When double-clicking this error - it took me to that erroneous web.config file, which tipped me off.

Answer (score 2):

It may be the version problem like you download the project of .Net framework 2.0 and want to open it into the VS2008 then you will need to upgrade to the latest version and VS will create the Backup of the folder in same root directory.You will get the answer [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robgruen/archive/2005/09/12/464196.aspx).

Comment: ranganh's answer [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/769696.aspx/1/10) provides some more details.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error when building the solution with Web Deployment Project created into my solution. I resolve the error by deleting the folder where Web Deployment Project is built to. This folder is specified in "Project Folder" attribute of WDP properties

Answer (score 2):

Delete bin and obj folders. Then rebuild the solution.

Comment: For File Explorer, use search query "obj" kind:=folder and "bin" kind:=folder to find/delete these folders. This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there were two web.config files in my solution. I am using MVC4 and there was another config file under Views and i was making the change in the wrong file. Fixed there helped me.

But you can always change the default redirect/route in the global.asax file.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have a sub asp.net project folder within the project folder which is not configured as virtual directory. Setup the project to run in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

I added to my website publish script. At the end, delete the obj folder from your website folder.

Comment: you might have some insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986738/error-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyond-application-level

Answer (score 1):

I've this problem more frequent if "true" is enabled in the project file.

1. Set false

As Jonny says:

1. Clean solution whilst your solution is configured in Release mode.
2. Clean solution whilst your solution is configured in Debug mode.
3. Build whilst your solution is configured in Debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

I had a project that I didn't want to be a web application I wanted  it to be a folder. The answer was to delete the web.config file altogether. It only belongs in the root of an application.

Answer (score 1):

If you face this problem while publishing your website or application on some server, the simple solution I used is to convert folder which contains files to web application.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please expand your answer? Could you explain how to convert the folder to a Web Application? This'll help others understand your answer better.

Comment: In IIS Manager, under the Connections pane on the right, you right-click the directory under the sites you've created (or Default Web Site), and choose `Convert to Application`.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem in VS 2013 after publishing my project in debug mode. The problem has been solved by removing obj/ files

Answer (score 1):

I have a website project.

In my case I had moved the solution file to another path and that cause the problem. I restored it to the previous location and the problem went out.

Answer (score 1):

For any one still looking, my solution was to delete both the bin and obj folders and restart visual studio seems to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Via Visual Studio, I had [published a WCF Service via FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39808645/1380710), to an external server. It worked fine locally, and when publishing to an internal server, but not to the external. The solution was to **publish without providing a** `Site Path` (in other words, publish directly to the root of the virtual directory).

I'm not sure why it worked, since I had already tried moving the files to the root via an external FTP Client - among many other attempts, including all listed here. Maybe it was something with the publish profile, like it was for [FabianVal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25297061/1380710). But I'm not in the mood of testing anymore at this point, since I'm in a hurry to get up to speed after all the days wasted on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

tip 1:    clean & then rebuild.

tip 2:    just close VS and open again.

tip 3:    the downloaded project may be inside another sub folder... open the folder which   has you .net files.

c:/demo1/demo/
(all files)

You should have to open demo from vs... not demo1.

Answer (score 0):

I tried every solution above, but none of them worked for my problem. (I'm sure there are 1000 solutions to this problem) For my scenario, I was attempting to publish my WCF web service that I had in test into production.

However, I failed to realize that in production we are HTTPS only, meaning we redirect everything to HTTPS. As it turns out, I was pointing to the service via HTTP instead of HTTPS, thus causing the error. The solution in this scenario was to simply to change the address protocol to HTTPS rather than HTTP.

I hope that helps some poor soul out there trying to figure out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was hosting with GoDaddy which wasn't the problem but it added a layer of confusion.

I had a root folder "WebServices" and set that as the application root.

HOWEVER the service was in a subfolder called "GeoLocateSpecials" as the "WebServices" folder is a container for many services.

So I had to set GeoLocateSpecials as an application root and it worked great from there.

Hope that helps anyone else out there.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue when I would publish the site, if I build the site I get no issues but while publishing I would get this awful error:

> "It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS"

I tried everything that has been stated here in this post to no resort, what worked for me was to just create a new publish profile with exactly the same as the one I've been using and that works well, don't get the error with the new profile but do with the old. Not sure what the difference is but at least I can publish my MVC project.

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

After deleting Crystal Reports Backup Files from the project  folder it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we were deploying a site out to a server which was replicated across other servers.  Performing an IISRESET on all servers in the deployment environment worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because a new global Web.Config is automatically created for the parent folder.  It was \Website\Website.

After I moved all file from the child folder to the parent and delete the child folder, now I have only one Web.Config and the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple `web.config` in same project creates this problem, this could haven created inside/due to `Area,views` folders.

The solution could be to change the main/root web.config settings to:

> ```
> Build Action - Content
> Copy to Output - Do not Copy
> ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have Asp.Net Website and I was getting this issue on publish only. The solution that worked for me is id deleted the **.vs** folder from my code and rebuild the application and then tried to publish and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You might not always depend upon the luck to clean-up your solution and rebuild it to expect the issue magically disappear.
This problem is due to Web.config file getting copied to output directory, here in this case "*\bin*".

Look for below code in your project file and just comment or remove altogether `<CopyToOutputDirectory>` from the `<content>` tag.

```
<Content Include="Web.config">
    <!-- <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory> -->
</Content>
```