# Error while running ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I am running an application which was downloaded from internet but get an error:

> It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

In web.config line 23 where code is:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

How to resolve this problem?

Note: I have only one web.config file then too this error. Help Appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The web.config file is in a directory that is not configured in IIS as an application.  You can fix this by configuring the directory as an application using IIS Manager.

The details depend on which version of Windows you are using: for example with Windows 7 you would right click on the directory in IIS Manager and select "Convert to Application".

Answer (score 0):

Make the virtual directory that your application lives in an application. Go to the IIS manager, locate the web site and the directory you installed your app to, right click it and select "Convert to Application".

Also see [Error: allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355947/error-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyond-application-level)