# Error:beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS

Tags: asp.net

I inherited this application from a developer who no longer with the company.
After I get latest and run the app, I get the following error:

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error:

```
Line 170:  <location path="winLogin.aspx">
Line 171:    <system.web>
Line 172:      <authentication mode="Windows" />
Line 173:      <authorization>
Line 174:        <allow users="*" />
```

The error mentions IIS however since this is a VS 2005 project I am using the default web browser.

Any ideas on how to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can define

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

inside of a `<location>` because that is an application-level setting.  In other words, you can't use different authentication modes for different web pages in the same application.  You will need to define this in the main `<system.web>` section of your configuration file instead.

The error message is just referring to one possible source of the error.  Usage of *any* application-level setting inside of a `<location>` tag or in a child `web.config` file in a subfolder of an application root will generate this error message as well.

If you truly need multiple authentication methods, you can create a subfolder as a virtual application and define it there, for example, `/winLogin/Default.aspx` page controlled by configuration settings in `/winLogin/web.config`.

### Update

Are you sure you can’t?
I just checked the QA web site where this app is running fine and the Web.config has the following entries:

```
<location path="winLogin.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authentication mode="Windows" /> 
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

The problem I am having is on my dev / local machine

Comment: Are you sure you can’t?
I just checked the QA web site where this app is running fine and the Web.config has the following entries:
<location path="winLogin.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authentication mode="Windows" /> 
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

Comment: Can you add it to your question post.  I could be wrong.  Looking around you may also see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355947/error-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyond-application-level

Comment: mellamokb See entries above, thx for the link. I will look these over first thing tmrw am

Comment: Sure. I may end up deleting this answer if you prove me wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check your application folder.

Either there is a backup copy of the application within the your application root folder.

or you have a duplicate **Web.config** file somewhere within the application.

Another thing you should do is go to **C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files** and delete all folders related to your application name. If it is your development box then you can delete everything under this folder.

Hope this will fix the issue.