# Error: allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. Running in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have build a web application that runs fine though Visual studio, but now i have it test it in IIS and receive the following errors.

> An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file
>   required to service this request
>
> It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS

What changes should i make in web.config or elsewhere to make this work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355947/error-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyond-application-level)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can means two thinks

1. You have a web.config on a sub-directory of your web application, that contains definitions that is not allowed for sub-directory
2. You try to run your site in a sub-directory of your web application with out first make it runable-application

Answer (score 0):

In my case deleting the obj folder fixed the problem