# How to solve the following errors in Web.config

Tags: asp.net

here is the error that is occuring at runtime

```
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error: 


Line 25:             ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
Line 26:         -->
Line 27:        <authentication mode="Forms"/>
Line 28:        <!--
Line 29:             The <customErrors> section enables configuration 

Source File: F:\Final Event Management\event management\web.config    Line: 27
```

and it is the coding in which error is genrating

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>

        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        </compilation>

        <authentication mode="Forms"/>

        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/></system.web>

</configuration>
```

please solve this problem.............

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild.. It worked for me once.

Comment: There was a bit similar post...<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355947/error-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyond-application-level> try if that helps in any ways..

Answer (score 2):

Create a virtual directory and see if that solves the problem:

[How to: Create IIS Virtual Directories in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6cw6cfs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Right-click project node in Solution Explorer Window and select Properties, then the Web tab and you should see a button to create a virtual directory for your site.

Comment: Right-click project node and select Properties