# Virtual directory error in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am fairly new to asp.net when I tried to launch my website today I received this error:

Error 2 It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Could someone please explain what this error means and how I can resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: check google results https://www.google.com/search?q=allowDefinition%3D'MachineToApplication'+beyond+application+level.+This+error+can+be+caused+by+a+virtual+directory+not+being+configured+as+an+application+in+IIS.&oq=allowDefinition%3D'MachineToApplication'+beyond+application+level.+This+error+can+be+caused+by+a+virtual+directory+not+being+configured+as+an+application+in+IIS.&aqs=chrome.0.57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: See if this similar post will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355947/error-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyond-application-level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you don't have the directory for your application defined as a virtual directory in IIS, or you have something not allowed in a web.config which is in a child directory. Some elements can only exist in the root web.config.