# Why won't my forms authentication stay logged in?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I'm using forms authentication on my mvc project, and it seems that no matter what I do.  You can only stay logged in for one day then it requires you to log in again.

In my web.config, I set the timeout to a week in minutes.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="10080" defaultUrl="/kpi" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

And here is where I'm setting the cookie.

```
var cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(account.UserName, account.RememberMe);
if (account.RememberMe)
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
var returnURL = FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(account.UserName, account.RememberMe);
var hashData = Request.Form["HashHidden"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime IIS recycles the app, a new machine key is generated. Your auth ticket is signed using that machine key, so when a new one is generated, the auth ticket is no longer recognized. You need to set a static machine key in your web.config.

http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey

Comment: This sounds like the right track.  I checked my app pool, and it's set to recycle every 29 hours, which does match up.  Do I just drop the generated key into the configuration section of web.config?

Comment: Yup, just paste it into the `<system.web>` portion of the web.config

Comment: Okay, so this is definitely the answer.  I've pushed it to the server and recycled the app pool and I stay logged in.  But the problem is that I can't debug my solution any more.  I get this error `It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. `  Would you know how to work around this?

Comment: That's odd. I've never encountered that when setting a machine key. That seems like an IIS configuration / web.config error to me. Unfortunately, I don't know how to help with that one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355947/error-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyond-application-level Maybe one of these might help?

Comment: Yeah, I've looked through that thread and nothing worked.  I've seen a few people say that I have to turn the folder into an application in iis, but that's way too kludgey for me.  especially if anybody tries to grab this solution from source control.

Comment: Got it working.  I deleted the setting, and went through IIS to generate the machinekey.  I added that key to my web.config in my test environment and everybody's happy. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the AuthCookie with `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, persistent)` See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

And set the proper timeout in your web.config

```
  <system.web>
     <authentication mode="Forms">
             <forms timeout="10080" slidingExpiration="true"/>
     </authentication>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm using `GetAuthCookie` which does the same, but returns the cookie instead of setting the cookie for me.