# Using a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"  />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <location path="Login.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="~/Login.aspx">
     </customErrors>
    <authentication mode="Windows">
     </authentication>
</System.web>
```

Comment: What did you not understand? Where is this config file located?

Comment: Web.Config file is located in Main directory.

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355947/error-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyond-application-level

Comment: What is "Main" directory?