# Copying mini website into main website giving configuration error

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, web-config

Recently,

I developed one mini site and had to deploy that site in one of our main project.

What I did is, I copied the whole mini project and pasted into the main project. And when I tried running the mini project, I got error as

```
 *It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.*
```

Also, the error was generated from  my mini `web.config` file from the line no : 45. Where the code was

```
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
```

I don't know what was the error all about. I also tried searching on the net for the issue and I got one link from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355947/error-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyond-application-level) but it also didn't helped me out.

Please suggest something which can be of any help. Also let me know know If I have to make some changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after researching so much, I got my answer.

What I need to do is(My mistake)

1. Converted the `Web.Config` file of the mini site as `Convert to Application.`

After that I got error as `Excel03ConString` already exist. For that, I commented out that line from the mini site.

Next, When I browsed the site I got error as: `The Site needs default document` as it was giving Membership page which comes by default.

SO I selected the default page and it started working smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("*Link of your website.com*");

or please try iframe.

Answer (score 0):

The error is very specific as to what the problem is. You need to configure the virtual directory your "mini site" is in as an application in IIS.

Open up Internet Information Services Manager, expand the list of sites until you find your "mini site". Right click on it and choose "Convert to Application". Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you need to mount the mini site as an application.  What version of IIS are you using?  The following steps for IIS 7 may help:

[Creating a Web Application (Virtual Directory) in IIS 7](http://www.helpmasterpro.com/helpfile/Web%20Modules/html%20files/Virtual%20Directory%20-%20creating%20in%20iis7.htm)

In case of link-rot, I'll summarise the points as well:

- Open IIS Manager
- Right-click on your master site and select "Add Application"
- Fill out the resulting dialogue box.  The alias is the "subfolder" the app will be mounted within, and the physical path is the directory your "mini site" resides in

Hope that helps.