# Publishing Website Using Visual Studio Web Dev Express

Tags: asp.net, visual-web-developer

How can I publish a website in Visual Web Development Express since Publish Website Utility is not available in this edition? Or is more advisable to convert my website into project or open my project in a Visual Studio?

I tried to copy aspx files and web.config into my IIS but I got error such :

`"It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.`

Comment: Can you get VS Community Edition? it is free and you can publish with it...

Comment: I tried installing visual studio but i need a newer version of windows.

Comment: What version of VS do you have?

Comment: Visual Studio Web Developer 2010 Express.

Comment: I suppose you can just copy and paste your aspx's, web.config and your dll's to your server (by hand)

Comment: got this error.  It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level

Comment: Edit your post and put a screenshot of your error

Comment: Check this answer also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355947/error-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyond-application-level

Comment: can't post a picture. don't have enough reputation