# How can I resolve "allowDefinition" error in Visual Studio 2013 when I'm taking over a project?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I'm taking over a web project (and in turn learn some asp.net). I'm running "Visual Studio 2013 for Web" on Windows 8.1. I've added a few elements to page and I'm attempting to build the site using `Debug -> Build Website`. When I do I get this error:

```
It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
```

I've placed the files for the project in a `project -> [project name]`. I've been reviewing information for "creating a virtual directory" but it's all written for people who seem to have been working in with this platform.

My main experience is in front end, php, and LAMP stack languages. I assume this means I need to tell the folder where the files are to treat it as a "server" kinda like I do with MAMP but I'm not sure if that's correct or even how to resolve the issue.

Here is my `web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the  
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section requirePermission="false" name="microsoft.identityModel" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Configuration.MicrosoftIdentityModelSection, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <!--<sectionGroup name="telerik">
      <section name="sitefinity" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Configuration.SectionHandler, Telerik.Sitefinity" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>-->
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="TestLocalization" value="false" />
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
  <location path="Sitefinity/CMIS/RestAtom">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="6048000" executionTimeout="7200" maxUrlLength="102400" maxQueryStringLength="102400" requestValidationType="Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Claims.CustomRequestValidator, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <location path="Telerik.Sitefinity.Html5UploadHandler.ashx">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="6048000" executionTimeout="7200" maxUrlLength="102400" maxQueryStringLength="102400" requestValidationType="Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Claims.CustomRequestValidator, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
          <!--2GB-->
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <location path="RestApi">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
      </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
    <!--Required for IIS7-->
    <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <handlers>
        <remove name="ServiceStack.Factory" />
        <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" maxUrlLength="102400" maxQueryStringLength="10000" requestValidationType="Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Claims.CustomRequestValidator, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
    <siteMap defaultProvider="SitefinitySiteMap">
      <providers>
        <add name="SitefinitySiteMap" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.SitefinitySiteMap, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
      </providers>
    </siteMap>
    <roleManager enabled="false" />
    <membership defaultProvider="Default">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="Default" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Data.SitefinityMembershipProvider, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <globalization uiCulture="auto" culture="auto" resourceProviderFactoryType="Telerik.Sitefinity.Localization.ExtendedResourceProviderFactory, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
    <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart="50">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add assembly="WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add assembly="PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <remove extension=".svc" />
        <add extension=".svc" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceBuildProvider, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
    <authentication mode="Forms" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" />
        <add tagPrefix="sitefinity" namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Fields" assembly="Telerik.Sitefinity" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
      <add verb="*" validate="false" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" />
      <add verb="*" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.RadUploadProgressHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" />
      <add verb="*" path="Telerik.Sitefinity.FilesDownloadHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Files.FilesDownloadHandler, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
      <add verb="*" path="Telerik.Sitefinity.ExportSubscribersHttpHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Newsletters.Web.ExportSubscribersHttpHandler, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
      <add verb="*" path="Telerik.Sitefinity.LibrariesRadUploadHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Libraries.Web.LibrariesRadUploadHandler, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
      <add verb="*" path="Telerik.Sitefinity.ThumbnailUploadHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Libraries.Web.ThumbnailUploadHandler, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false" />
      <add verb="*" validate="false" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" />
      <add verb="*" path="Telerik.Sitefinity.AsyncImageUploadHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Libraries.Web.AsyncImageUploadHandler, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
      <add verb="*" path="Telerik.Sitefinity.AsyncFileUploadHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Workflow.AsyncFileUploadHandler, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
      <add verb="*" path="Telerik.Sitefinity.AsyncToolsetXmlUploadHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Configuration.Web.Services.AsyncToolsetXmlUploadHandler, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
      <add verb="*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" validate="false" />
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" validate="false" />
      <add verb="*" path="Telerik.ReportViewer.axd" type="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.HttpHandler, Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms" />
      <add verb="*" path="*.css,*.js,*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.gif,*.png,*.xml,*.mp4" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
      <add verb="*" path="Telerik.Sitefinity.Html5UploadHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Libraries.Web.Html5UploadHandler, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="RoleManager" />
      <add name="ClaimsPrincipalHttpModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.ClaimsPrincipalHttpModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add name="SitefinityClaimsAuthenticationModule" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Claims.SitefinityClaimsAuthenticationModule, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
      <add name="Sitefinity" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.SitefinityHttpModuleIIS6, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Claims.SitefinitySessionAuthenticationModule, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule, Telerik.Web.UI" />
      <add name="SitefinityAnalyticsModule" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Analytics.Server.DependencyResolution.Module.DependencyRegistrarHttpModule, Telerik.Sitefinity.Analytics.Server.Infrastructure" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
        <!-- note: To enable https/SSL support for the Analytics module, uncomment this binding -->
        <!--<binding name="webBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>-->
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SitefinityWebApp.Sitefinity.Services.Content.EventsAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="EndpBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <!--<openAccessWorkflowTracking applicationName="/workflow" />-->
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.Services.LocalizationBehavior" />
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="SitefinityWebApp.Sitefinity.Services.Content.Events">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="SitefinityWebApp.Sitefinity.Services.Content.EventsAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SitefinityWebApp.Sitefinity.Services.Content.Events" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule" />
      <remove name="ScriptModule" />
      <remove name="RadUploadModule" />
      <remove name="Sitefinity" />
      <remove name="SitefinityAnalyticsModule" />
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="RoleManager" />
      <add name="ClaimsPrincipalHttpModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.ClaimsPrincipalHttpModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add name="SitefinityClaimsAuthenticationModule" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Claims.SitefinityClaimsAuthenticationModule, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
      <add name="Sitefinity" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.SitefinityHttpModule, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Claims.SitefinitySessionAuthenticationModule, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule, Telerik.Web.UI" />
      <add name="SitefinityAnalyticsModule" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Analytics.Server.DependencyResolution.Module.DependencyRegistrarHttpModule, Telerik.Sitefinity.Analytics.Server.Infrastructure" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory" />
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" />
      <remove name="ScriptResource" />
      <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler" />
      <remove name="WildCard" />
      <remove name="WildCard32" />
      <remove name="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" />
      <remove name="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler" />
      <remove name="Telerik.Sitefinity.FilesDownloadHandler" />
      <remove name="Telerik.Sitefinity.ExportSubscribersHttpHandler" />
      <remove name="Telerik.Sitefinity.LibrariesRadUploadHandler" />
      <remove name="Telerik.Sitefinity.AsyncImageUploadHandler" />
      <remove name="Telerik.Sitefinity.AsyncFileUploadHandler" />
      <remove name="Telerik.Sitefinity.AsyncToolsetXmlUploadHandler" />
      <remove name="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" />
      <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" />
      <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" />
      <remove name="Telerik.Sitefinity.Html5UploadHandler" />
      <add name="Sitefinity 64 bit .xamlx script map" path="*.xamlx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" />
      <add name="Sitefinity .xamlx script map" path="*.xamlx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" />
      <add name="Sitefinity 64 bit .svc script map" path="*.svc" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" />
      <add name="Sitefinity .svc script map" path="*.svc" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" />
      <add name="Sitefinity .xamlx handler" path="*.xamlx" verb="*" type="System.Xaml.Hosting.XamlHttpHandlerFactory, System.Xaml.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="Sitefinity .svc handler" path="*.svc" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <add name="WildCard" path="*" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" />
      <add name="WildCard32" path="*" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" />
      <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" />
      <add name="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.RadUploadProgressHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" />
      <add name="Telerik.Sitefinity.FilesDownloadHandler" path="Telerik.Sitefinity.FilesDownloadHandler.ashx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Files.FilesDownloadHandler, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
      <add name="Telerik.Sitefinity.ExportSubscribersHttpHandler" path="Telerik.Sitefinity.ExportSubscribersHttpHandler.ashx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Newsletters.Web.ExportSubscribersHttpHandler, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
      <add name="Telerik.Sitefinity.LibrariesRadUploadHandler" path="Telerik.Sitefinity.LibrariesRadUploadHandler.ashx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Libraries.Web.LibrariesRadUploadHandler, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
      <add name="Telerik.Sitefinity.ThumbnailUploadHandler" path="Telerik.Sitefinity.ThumbnailUploadHandler.ashx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Libraries.Web.ThumbnailUploadHandler, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
      <add name="Telerik.Sitefinity.AsyncImageUploadHandler" path="Telerik.Sitefinity.AsyncImageUploadHandler.ashx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Libraries.Web.AsyncImageUploadHandler, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
      <add name="Telerik.Sitefinity.AsyncFileUploadHandler" path="Telerik.Sitefinity.AsyncFileUploadHandler.ashx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Workflow.AsyncFileUploadHandler, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
      <add name="Telerik.Sitefinity.AsyncToolsetXmlUploadHandler" path="Telerik.Sitefinity.AsyncToolsetXmlUploadHandler.ashx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Configuration.Web.Services.AsyncToolsetXmlUploadHandler, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
      <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" />
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" verb="*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" />
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" />
      <add name="Telerik.ReportViewer.axd_*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.ReportViewer.axd" type="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.HttpHandler, Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms" />
      <add name="Telerik.Sitefinity.Html5UploadHandler" path="Telerik.Sitefinity.Html5UploadHandler.ashx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Libraries.Web.Html5UploadHandler, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
    </handlers>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="31.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
    <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false" />
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="default.aspx" />
        <add value="Default.htm" />
        <add value="Default.asp" />
        <add value="index.htm" />
        <add value="index.html" />
        <add value="iisstart.htm" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="10000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <microsoft.identityModel>
    <service>
      <claimsAuthenticationManager type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Claims.SFClaimsAuthenticationManager, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <add type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Claims.SWT.SWTSecurityTokenHandler, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
      </securityTokenHandlers>
      <audienceUris mode="Never" />
      <federatedAuthentication>
        <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="http://localhost" realm="http://localhost" requireHttps="false" />
        <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
      </federatedAuthentication>
      <issuerNameRegistry type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Claims.CustomIssuerNameRegistry, Telerik.Sitefinity">
        <trustedIssuers />
      </issuerNameRegistry>
      <issuerTokenResolver type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Claims.SWT.WrapIssuerTokenResolver, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
    </service>
  </microsoft.identityModel>
  <!-- Begin telerik section  -->
  <!--<telerik>
    <sitefinity>
      <environment platform="WindowsAzure"/>
      <sitefinityConfig storageMode="Database" />
    </sitefinity>
  </telerik>-->
  <!-- End telerik section  -->
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

The error says the issue is as line 79: `<siteMap defaultProvider="SitefinitySiteMap">` and I'm loading from the root not a parent folder.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355947/error-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyond-application-level

Comment: I've used the `clean` option when building out Windows Apps in Cordova or  native Android apps to solve issues. Don't see the option for this project though...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create a new web site in IIS (make sure its app pool targets .NET 4), put a hostname of the site like mysite.localtest.me (don't worry, this will resolve to 127.0.0.1) and point the site to the root folder of your project. Then in Visual Studio go to properties of the SitefinityWebApp project and find the Web tab - in the servers dropdown select Local IIS and under project url put the hostname from above: http://mysite.localtest.me

Save and build.