# Error occurred in forms authentication in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I wanted to create a form which anonymous user can't access without having a password. I tried this piece of configuration in my web.config file.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx">
    <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
      <user name="xxx" password="xxx"/>
    </credentials>
  </forms>        
</authentication>
```

After i deployed the application i get error like this in my web browser

> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
>
> Source Error:

Can anybody tell me what is happening and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you configure the folder that the site is hosted in as an application within IIS?

Comment: yes i did. is that the problem?

Comment: @progmo No, that's not the problem. IIS is interpreting the opposite and giving this error. Is there multiple web.config files present in the directory structure? Have you checked event viewer and IIS Logs for troubleshooting? What's the windows and IIS version?

Comment: @Nimesh can you please tell me how checked event viewer and IIS logs. I don't know how to checked them ?

Comment: DId you check the responses from [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355947/error-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyond-application-level?rq=1)?