# Error in web.config file in asp.net webform application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am stuck at this and cannot figure it out why it is not working. When i open my website it shows me this error.If you can help me I'll be grateful. It is giving error at membership line and i cannot figure it out why it is giving this error.It is giving the Configuration Error. Below is the description of the error.

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error:

```
Line 52:       </controls>
Line 53:     </pages>
Line 54:     <membership>
Line 55:       <providers>
Line 56:         <!--
```

Comment: how about that ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355947/error-allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyond-application-level