# Unable to access Login form in Umbraco 7.5.4 after deploying the web-application on Internet

Tags: iis, web-config, umbraco, web-deployment, umbraco7

After deploying my web application on internet, I cannot access to Login form for umbraco admin back-office `[http://www.cake-and-art.de//umbraco][1]`

I've encountered an error.

How can I solve it? Please help me.
I've used `Umbraco 7.5.4` and `ASP.NET MVC`

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Runtime Error
>
> Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current
>   custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the
>   application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons).
>   It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server
>   machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be
>   viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within
>   a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the
>   current web application. This  tag should then have its
>   "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

> Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a
>   custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the
>   application's  configuration tag to point to a custom
>   error page URL.

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I changed the value of `customErrors mode` to `Off` in `web.config` file.

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
    <trace enabled="false" requestLimit="10" pageOutput="false" traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="true" />
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" enableVersionHeader="false" targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="51200" fcnMode="Single" />
```

**And now I see this error:**

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error
>   settings for this application prevent the details of the application
>   error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could,
>   however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
>
> Source File: C:\ClientSites\cake-and-art.de\httpdocs\web.config
>   Line: 406

**In webconfig file:**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="yourAuthCookie" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" path="/" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the customerrors mode to Off to show the actual error?

Comment: Check out the log file (located in App_Data/Logs) to see what's wrong. Maybe something with the connectionstring?

Comment: @Eyescream: Now you can see.

Comment: @Mark the connection string is correct because I can see my homepage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2355947/1817640) in `stackoverflow.com`, I could solve the problem.

I cleaned project solution, rebuild it and finally deployed it.